# MYSQL syntax error while using MATCH () AGAINST()

Tags: php, mysql, match-against

I trying to query a database to find relevant results between two columns in separate tables, to do this I'm using the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE MATCH (TITLE) AGAINST ($description) AND ARTIST=$band ORDER BY relevance DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Result False on line 47: $result <br>
            Query: $query <br>
            Error: " . mysql_error());
    }
```

As you might expect the error message appears saying I have an error in my MYSQL syntax but I'm not sure what it is, any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AGAINST ($description)` should be `AGAINST ('$description')`

`ARTIST=$band` should be `ARTIST='$band'`

Any strings that are processed through queries need single quotes ( ' ) around them, and column names with spaces need backticks ( ` ).

If `$description` or `$band` contain any quotes or slashes you will need to escape them using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (I'd recommend doing this anyway)

Also, you can consolidate your `die` statement into your query line:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(
"Result False on line 47: $result <br>
            Query: $query <br>
            Error: " . mysql_error()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even syntax is correct this error is coming because some SQL version dont support this syntax.

Make sure your MySQL version is supporting this query or not before looking into other way around.